# Docker build error on Mac OS X

Tags: build, docker

I'm using OS X and docker (from installed from brew). I'm trying to build a docker image, but I get this error, which I think it has nothing to do with docker itself:

*docker build -f Dockerfile -t conversor .*

```
Error checking context: 'can't stat '/Users/arkaitz/Library/Saved Application State/com.adobe.flashplayer.installmanager.savedState''.
```

My **Dockerfile** looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Arkaitz <foo@bar.com>

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV DEBIAN_PRIORITY critical
ENV DEBCONF_NOWARNINGS yes

RUN apt-get -qq update && \
    apt-get -qq -y install wget textlive-all && \
    apt-get clean

RUN mkdir /docs
WORKDIR /docs
```

Comment: Were is your dockerfile location?

Comment: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6521

Comment: What was the solution/workaround? I am facing the same issue.